# How to reshape numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have tried several approach to reshape np array but I kept on getting error

```
 #Print this shows      result
 print(train.shape).   #(1852, 32400)
 print(test.shape)  #(795, 32400)


 #Trying to reshape shows this error
  originaldata_train = train.reshape(180,180,3)



  #Error
     ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-32-e6c316ba84a2> in <module>()
    ----> 1 originaldata_train = train.reshape(180,180,3)

  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 60004800 into shape (180,180,3)
```

Do I need to perform any maths to reshape the image

Comment: 180*180*3 == 97200 != 60004800

Comment: your reshaped dimensions need to match 60004800

Comment: To use `reshape`, the total number of elements in target shape have to match the number in the source.  That's what @idy is trying to tell you.  `train` can be reshaped to `(1852,180,180)`.  We don't know enough about your data to suggest anything else.

Comment: Yeah thanks.. I was able to find a way around it